# Extracting particular text associated value from an image

Tags: python, opencv, ocr

I have an image, and from the image I want to extract key and value pair details.

As an example, I want to extract the value of "MASTER-AIRWAYBILL NO:"

[image]

I have written to extract the entire text from the image using python opencv and OCR, but I don't have any clue how to extract only the value for "MASTER-AIRWAYBILL NO:" from the entire result text of the image.

Please find the code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image
print ("Hello")
src_path = "C:\\Users\Venkatraman.R\Desktop\\alpha_bill.jpg"
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"


print (src_path)


# Read image with opencv
img = cv2.imread(src_path)

# Convert to gray
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Apply dilation and erosion to remove some noise
kernel = np.ones((1, 1), np.uint8)
img = cv2.dilate(img, kernel, iterations=1)
img = cv2.erode(img, kernel, iterations=1)

# Write image after removed noise
cv2.imwrite(src_path + "removed_noise.png", img)

#  Apply threshold to get image with only black and white
#img = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 31, 2)

# Write the image after apply opencv to do some ...
cv2.imwrite(src_path + "thres.png", img)

# Recognize text with tesseract for python
result = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(src_path + "thres.png"))


# Remove template file
#os.remove(temp)


print ('--- Start recognize text from image ---')
print (result)
```

So output should be like:

> MASTER-AIRWAYBILL NO: 157-46637194

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pytesseract` [image_to_string()](https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/) and a [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) to extract the desired text, i.e.:

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract, re
f = "ocr.jpg"
t = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(f))
m = re.findall(r"MASTER-AIRWAYBILL NO: [\d—-]+", t)
if m:
    print(m[0])
```

---

Output:

```
MASTER-AIRWAYBILL NO: 157—46637194
```

Comment: Output is printing empty

Comment: As usual, I've tested the answer's code (python 3.6) and it works as expected. The image file I've used is the same as in your question: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKebi.jpg. Care to comment the down-vote?

Comment: Even am using the same, I checked by printing the t it’s printing but it’s not printing the value of m

Comment: I used the latest version of `pytesseract` for `py3.6`. If you're not using it, please update it. I cannot see any other reason for your results being different from mine.

Comment: Am using 3.7.1 version of python

Comment: What if i want the value for consignee then from the image ?

Answer (score 0):

I m using python 2.7 and I also want to find vendor name from the image
how should I find?

`m = re.findall(r"MASTER-AIRWAYBILL NO: [\d—-]+", t)`
the above line gives error and if I use
`m=re.findall(r'Vendor Name:[\d--]+', t)`
also gives error ..

Comment: Welcome to SO, if you are facing an issue please post a new question, this does not provide an answer to OP. Once you have enough reputation, you can add comment to OP.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this after installing tesseract.

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract, re
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"
t = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open("path"))
m = re.findall(r"Invoice No. [\d—-]+", t)
if m:
    print(m[0])
```