# Why everybody convert image to gray-scale before performing operations on openCV

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing

been trying to find the answer to why everybody converts an image to grayscale before processing?

For example, [this website](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/09/01/build-kick-ass-mobile-document-scanner-just-5-minutes/) with instructions teaching people how to build a simple scanning program converts photo to greyscale first before passing commands to manipulate the image itself.

In the second example, [this thread on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54559899/extracting-particular-text-associated-value-from-an-image) shows a person also converts the image to grayscale before extracting text from his image.

Does this process make the image easier to manipulate? Or does it give better results when extracting text? If so, shouldn't a binary image give the best result in the case of extracting text?

Comment: Converting to greyscale shouldn't be seen as a necessary first step and panacea for all ills when image processing as the colour information can often be useful. I suspect most people do it in the interests of saving 2/3 the memory, or 2/3 of the processing time.

Comment: Yes that makes the images easier to manipulate specially for processes like thresholding, morphological operations, contrast enhancement and shape analysis. Color images are better for more sophisticated operation like image segmentation, face detection and so on.

Comment: many algorithms from literature only work on image intensity.

Comment: in addition, color can be misleading, since colored light often changes the color appearance of scenes. Sometimes this can be fixed with white balancing or image normalization, but this isnt always true.

Comment: An additional reason why I sometimes convert images to gray-scale is to get **sharper** images. The reason is that all but the most expensive cameras have chromatic aberration. This effectively zooms the red and blue channels by up to a few pixels. In these cases I take the green channel because it not only has the least aberration, it also has the least noise. Just taking the weighed grayscale will in this case actually blur the image more, the farther from the center you are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More often than not, grayscale has all the relevant information to complete a particular task. So reducing the image to grayscale greatly simplifies calculations and removes redundancies.

Binary image is great too but it sacrifices too many information for it to be useful in many cases. And most library supports a minimum of 8 bit image processing anyway for a true binary data structure to be useful.

Imagine having to create a program to recognize text on paper. Having a color image doesn't help you to better read the text. The text can be in various color but you can read the text even if its in black and white. You can argue that binary image should also give the same performance and that is true IF there are no noise such as shadow on the paper.

Once there are noise elements exist on the image, you will need more information to separate text from noise and that is when grayscale is useful.

Moreover the most used and reliable information for advanced image processing is the edges and its textures. Both which can be obtained from a grayscale image.